# How move data from mssql database to Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have to move some data from sql server to access database. In target access database there are ready tables, I need to move only records. Some of them will require some changes, like crossing two tables from sql server to one access database. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Sql Server Integration Service and write a custom sql query in the step that prompts you to select tables or write a query

Comment: Salam Saeed jan, mokhlesetim refigh, vaght nemikonam ye moaddate karam ziad shode, khodet che khabar, oza ahvalet khobe